# Merged contacts keep separating (Google and LinkedIn)

Tags: contacts

I’ve got a Nexus 5 with Android 5.0 and after installing some applications handling contacts (Google Contacts, WhatsApp, LinkedIn) I got this terrible mess in my contacts. Thus, I merged some manually, definitely not very systematically. Just to make things clear, the main source of my contacts is my Google account.

The problem is the following: It seems that e.g. the LinkedIn app when automatically syncing its contacts first deletes them all (or what) and then it creates them again. This breaks all the merges that I did before and it is all in vain.

Is there a way how to make this work so that my contacts remain merged/linked/joined?

Thanks for help.